# Programmatically Unhide Slides in PPT File

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, hslf

I'm writing a little tool that converts slides in PPT Files to pngs, the problem I'm having is with hidden slides. How can I change a slide to be visible in java? Im currently using Apache POI for conversion to PNGs, although this doesn't work for clipart so I am tempted with exporting it to a PDF using unoconv first, then minipulating that. But doing it like this doesn't take in to account all the hidden slides. So how could I programmatically change the hidden slides to be visible?

Comment: Each slide has a .SlideShowTransition.Hidden property (Boolean) that governs whether it's hidden or not.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Where is this method?

Comment: It's part of the PowerPoint object model.  Whether POI and Java give you access to that or not, I don't know.  If you have access to the XML in the PPTX file, the slidenn.xml file will begin with something like:  <p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocumen
t/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" show="0"><p:cSld>  if the slide's hidden.  Unhidden slides will not have the show="0" part.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a hack and has been tested only with a PPT from Libre Office with POI 3.9 / POI-Scratchpad 3.8.

The [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313106.aspx) ([MS-PPT].pdf / version 3.0 / page 201) says, that Bit 3 (fHidden) of Byte 18 *specifies whether the corresponding slide is hidden and is not displayed during the slide show*

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.Record;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.RecordTypes;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.UnknownRecordPlaceholder;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;

public class UnhidePpt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("hiddenslide.ppt");
        SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(fis);
        fis.close();

        Field f = UnknownRecordPlaceholder.class.getDeclaredField("_contents");
        f.setAccessible(true);


        for (Slide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {
            for (Record record : slide.getSlideRecord().getChildRecords()) {
                if (record instanceof UnknownRecordPlaceholder
                    && record.getRecordType() == RecordTypes.SSSlideInfoAtom.typeID) {
                    UnknownRecordPlaceholder urp = (UnknownRecordPlaceholder)record;

                    byte contents[] = (byte[])f.get(urp);
                    contents[18] &= (255-4);
                    f.set(urp, contents);
                }
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("unhidden.ppt");
        ppt.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've submitted a [patch #55560](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55560). Lets see when it gets integrated ...